# How would I reference a viewModel in a unit test?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have the following action:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyIndexViewModel { TotalTips = (decimal)7.51 };
    return View(model);
}
```

I would like to write a unit test that verifies that model.TotalTips is 7.51.

I am trying something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange
    var controller = new MyController(_mockRepository.Object);
    MyIndexViewModel test = new MyIndexViewModel{TotalTips = (decimal)7.51};

    // Action
    ViewResult result = controller.Index();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(result.ViewData.Model.TotalTips, test.TotalTips); // Problem line
}
```

But I cannot resolve `TotalTips` on `result.ViewData.Model.TotalTips`.

I know this is wrong, but cannot figure out how to properly resolve the model I am posting to the Index view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary.model.aspx) `ViewDataDictionary.Model` is typed as object, so you'll have to cast it to your view model type:

```
var viewModel = (MyIndexViewModel)result.ViewData.Model;
Assert.AreEqual(viewModel.TotalTips, test.TotalTips);
```